# How to make a command to stop countdown in Python Discord Bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I would like to make this stoppable, by that I mean that a separate command (~cdstop) would cancel the countdown.

```
import discord
import asyncio

counter_channel = None

async def ex(args, message, client, invoke):

  global counter_channel
  if counter_channel is not None:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), "There is a counter in {}".format(counter_channel.mention)))
    return

  counter_channel = message.channel

  await client.send_message(message.channel, "5 Minutes")
  await asyncio.sleep(60)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "4 Minutes")
  await asyncio.sleep(60)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "3 Minutes")
  await asyncio.sleep(60)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "2 Minutes")
  await asyncio.sleep(60)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "1 Minutes")
  await asyncio.sleep(30)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "30 Seconds")
  await asyncio.sleep(15)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "15 Seconds")
  await asyncio.sleep(10)
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "5 Seconds")

  counter_channel = None
```

My idea for it is that after every print statement it would check if a user has typed ~cdstop and then break from the function. I think it would work but I don't know if it would be efficient as I know it would mess with the check for double countdown.

### Edit

Code that calls the file:

```
import discord
from discord import Game, Embed

import SECRETS
import STATICS
from commands import cmd_ping, cmd_clear, cmd_help, cmd_userinfo, cmd_cdstart

client = discord.Client()


commands = {

    "ping": cmd_ping,
    "clear": cmd_clear,
    "help": cmd_help,
    "userinfo": cmd_userinfo,
    "cdstart": cmd_cdstart,

}


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is logged in successfully. Running on servers:\n")
    [(lambda s: print("  - %s (%s)" % (s.name, s.id)))(s) for s in client.servers]
    await client.change_presence(game=Game(name="~help"))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(STATICS.PREFIX):
        invoke = message.content[len(STATICS.PREFIX):].split(" ")[0]
        args = message.content.split(" ")[1:]
        if commands.__contains__(invoke):
            await commands.get(invoke).ex(args, message, client, invoke)
        else:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=("The command `%s` is not valid!" % invoke)))

client.run(SECRETS.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016501/how-to-schedule-and-cancel-tasks-with-asyncio

Comment: Can't seem to get my solution from that thread. I did however have another solution that I'm testing.
Is there a command that would close the python file that time using so:

o = True
if o = True:
   **command to close file**

Is something like that possible?

Comment: You mean shut down your bot entirely?

Comment: All my commands are in separate files so what i mean is just to close that one command from running, so a way of doing that is to close that set command file? 
I don't know if it would work it was just a theory as I don't know what else to try.

Comment: I doubt that would work, because the coroutine is already executing in the event loop.  Could you share the code that calls this coroutine?

Comment: Edited original post to show this code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses [`AbstractEventLoop.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) to create a `Task` object that you can then [`Task.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) at any time.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
counter_channel = None
task = None

async def ex(message):

    global counter_channel
    if counter_channel is not None:
        await bot.send_message(
            message.channel,
            embed=discord.Embed("There is a counter in {}".format(counter_channel.mention), color=discord.Color.red() ))
        return

    counter_channel = message.channel
    # reduced waits for easy testing
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "5 Minutes")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "4 Minutes")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "3 Minutes")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await bot.send_message(message.channel, "2 Minutes")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    counter_channel = None

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def timer(ctx):
    global task
    task = bot.loop.create_task(ex(ctx.message))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def cancel(ctx):
    global task, counter_channel
    task.cancel()
    task = None
    counter_channel = None
```