# How to stop function from finishing its code in event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have event loop that runs the function asynchronously. However, that function generates big data so the execution will be a little bit long when the program visits that function. I also implemented a stop button, so the app will exit that function even if the event loop is not yet finish. The problem is that is how to exit on that function immediately or how to kill a thread in asyncio.

I already tried using a flag in the function but the execution of the function is fast enough to check the flag before the user click on the stop button. To be short, the thread already running on the background.

```
def execute_function(self, function_to_execute, *args):
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    self.future = self.loop.run_in_executor(self._executor, function_to_execute, *args)
    return self.future

def stop_function(self):
    if self._executor:
        self._executor.shutdown(wait=False)
    self.loop.stop()
    self.loop.close()
```

Is there something wrong or missing on the code I've given? The expected output should be, the program will not generate the data at the end if I click the stop button.

Comment: I don't have enough experience in asyncio to close this for certain, but is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016501/how-to-schedule-and-cancel-tasks-with-asyncio a duplicate?

Comment: Running in a thread is different than an async task.  You can't cancel a thread once it has started up as it is not running on the loop.

Comment: Thanks @MarkReedZ! Async is one of those things I keep *meaning* to learn to do in Python, but have never invested the time in it yet. All my real use cases for async I've actually done either in Go or Groovy, calling Python backends *shrug*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use threading.Event passing it to your blocking function

```
event = threading.Event()
future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocking, event)   
# When done
event.set()
```

The blocking function just has to check is_set and when you want to stop it just call event.set() as above.

```
def blocking(event):
  while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    if event.is_set():
      break
```