# Handling Timeouts with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

*Disclaimer: this is my first time experimenting with the `asyncio` module.*

I'm using `asyncio.wait` in the following manner to try to support a timeout feature waiting for all results from a set of async tasks. This is part of a larger library so I'm omitting some irrelevant code.

Note that the library already supports submitting tasks and using timeouts with ThreadPoolExecutors and ProcessPoolExecutors, so I'm not really interested in suggestions to use those instead or questions about why I'm doing this with `asyncio`. On to the code...

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress

... 

class AsyncIOSubmit(Node):
    def get_results(self, futures, timeout=None):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        finished, unfinished = loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.wait(futures, timeout=timeout)
        )
        if timeout and unfinished:
            # Code options in question would go here...see below.
            raise asyncio.TimeoutError
```

At first I was not worrying about cancelling pending tasks on timeout, but then I got the warning `Task was destroyed but it is pending!` on program exit or `loop.close`. After researching a bit I found multiple ways to cancel tasks and wait for them to actually be cancelled:

**Option 1:**

```
[task.cancel() for task in unfinished]
for task in unfinished:
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

**Option 2:**

```
[task.cancel() for task in unfinished]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(unfinished))
```

**Option 3:**

```
# Not really an option for me, since I'm not in an `async` method
# and don't want to make get_results an async method.
[task.cancel() for task in unfinished]
for task in unfinished:
    await task
```

**Option 4:**

Some sort of while loop like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022171/10682164) answer. Seems like my other options are better but including for completeness.

---

Options 1 and 2 both seem to work fine so far. Either option may be "right", but with `asyncio` evolving over the years the examples and suggestions around the net are either outdated or vary quite a bit. So my questions are...

**Question 1**

Are there any practical differences between Options 1 and 2? I know `run_until_complete` will run until the future has completed, so since Option 1 is looping in a specific order I suppose it could behave differently if earlier tasks take longer to actually complete. I tried looking at the asyncio source code to understand if `asyncio.wait` just effectively does the same thing with its tasks/futures under the hood, but it wasn't obvious.

**Question 2**

I assume if one of the tasks is in the middle of a long-running blocking operation it may not actually cancel immediately? Perhaps that just depends on if the underlying operation or library being used will raise the CancelledError right away or not? Maybe that should never happen with libraries designed for asyncio?

Since I'm trying to implement a timeout feature here I'm somewhat sensitive to this. If it's possible these things could take a long time to cancel I'd consider calling `cancel` and not waiting for it to actually happen, or setting a very short timeout to wait for the cancels to finish.

**Question 3**

Is it possible `loop.run_until_complete` (or really, the underlying call to `async.wait`) returns values in `unfinished` for a reason other than a timeout? If so I'd obviously have to adjust my logic a bit, but from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) it seems like that is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any practical differences between Options 1 and 2?

No. Option 2 looks nicer and might be marginally more efficient, but their net effect is the same.

> I know `run_until_complete` will run until the future has completed, so since Option 1 is looping in a specific order I suppose it could behave differently if earlier tasks take longer to actually complete.

It seems that way at first, but it's not actually the case because `loop.run_until_complete` runs **all** tasks submitted to the loop, not just the one passed as argument. It merely **stops** once the provided awaitable completes - that is what "run until complete" refers to. A loop calling `run_until_complete` over already scheduled tasks is like the following async code:

```py
ts = [asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(i)) for i in range(1, 11)]
# takes 10s, not 55s
for t in ts:
    await t
```

which is in turn semantically equivalent to the following threaded code:

```py
ts = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    t = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    ts.append(t)
# takes 10s, not 55s
for t in ts:
    t.join()
```

In other words, `await t` and `run_until_complete(t)` block until `t` has completed, but allow everything else - such as tasks previously scheduled using `asyncio.create_task()` to run during that time as well. So the total run time will equal the run time of the longest task, not of their sum. For example, if the first task happens to take a long time, all others will have finished in the meantime, and their awaits won't sleep at all.

All this only applies to awaiting tasks that have been previously scheduled. If you try to apply that to coroutines, it won't work:

```py
# runs for 55s, as expected
for i in range(1, 11):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)

# also 55s - we didn't call create_task() so it's equivalent to the above
ts = [asyncio.sleep(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
for t in ts:
    await t

# also 55s
for i in range(1, 11):
   t = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(i,))
   t.start()
   t.join()
```

This is often a sticking point for asyncio beginners, who write code equivalent to that last asyncio example and expect it to run in parallel.

> I tried looking at the asyncio source code to understand if `asyncio.wait` just effectively does the same thing with its tasks/futures under the hood, but it wasn't obvious.

`asyncio.wait` is just a convenience API that does two things:

- converts the input arguments to something that implements `Future`. For coroutines that means that it submits them to the event loop, as if with `create_task`, which allows them to run independently. If you give it tasks to begin with, as you do, this step is skipped.
- uses `add_done_callback` to be notified when the futures are done, at which point it resumes its caller.

So yes, it does the same things, but with a different implementation because it supports many more features.

> I assume if one of the tasks is in the middle of a long-running blocking operation it may not actually cancel immediately?

In asyncio there shouldn't be "blocking" operations, only those that suspend, and they should be cancelled immediately. The exception to this is blocking code tacked onto asyncio with `run_in_executor`, where the underlying operation won't cancel at all, but the asyncio coroutine will immediately get the exception.

> Perhaps that just depends on if the underlying operation or library being used will raise the CancelledError right away or not?

The library doesn't *raise* `CancelledError`, it *receives* it at the await point where it happened to suspend before cancellation occurred. For the library the effect of the cancellation is `await ...` interrupting its wait and immediately raising `CancelledError`. Unless caught, the exception will propagate through function and `await` calls all the way to the top-level coroutine, whose raising `CancelledError` marks the whole task as cancelled. Well-behaved asyncio code will do just that, possibly using `finally` to release OS-level resources they hold. When `CancelledError` is caught, the code can choose not to re-raise it, in which case cancellation is effectively ignored.

> Is it possible loop.run_until_complete (or really, the underlying call to `async.wait`) returns values in unfinished for a reason other than a timeout?

If you're using `return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETE` (the default), that shouldn't be possible. It is quite possible with `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`, then it is obviously possible independently of timeout.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. One quick question/clarification about your first Threading example...I assume you are just showing that as an analogous-but-not-exactly-the-same way to do this with threads. My assumption was that asyncio does not do any multithreading under the hood, just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding.

Comment: @totalhack Correct on all counts. Asyncio is fiercely single-threaded, and its implementation is completely different. As you correctly surmise, I was aiming to explain the concepts by drawing an analogy with equivalent concepts in threading.

Comment: "also 55s - we didn't call create_task() so it's equivalent to the above". So what if we continue with `result = await asyncio.gather(*ts)` or `for res in asyncio.as_completed(ts)...` after that? Does it take 55s? Since I'm using asyncio to capture thousands of links per second I'm interested in decreasing `create_task()` overhead by directly using the tasks list.

Comment: @Babak `gather` and `as_completed` will call `create_task` for you, so there should be no difference. Use the one that you find most elegant.