# How to chain coroutines in asyncio when fetch nested urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I'm currently designing a spider to crawl a specific website. I can do it synchronous but I'm trying to get my head around asyncio to make it as efficient as possible. I've tried a lot of different approaches, with `yield`, `chained functions` and `queues` but I can't make it work.

I'm most interested in the design part and logic to solve the problem. Not necessary runnable code, rather highlight the most important aspects of assyncio. I can't post any code, because my attempts are not worth sharing.

**The mission:**

The exemple.com (I know, it should be example.com) got the following design:

[image]

In synchronous manner the logic would be like this:

```
for table in my_url_list:
    # Get HTML
    # Extract urls from HTML to user_list
    for user in user_list:
        # Get HTML
        # Extract urls from HTML to user_subcat_list
        for subcat in user_subcat_list:
            # extract content
```

But now I would like to scrape the site asynchronous. Lets say we using 5 instances (tabs in pyppeteer or requests in aiohttp) to parse the content. How should we design it to make it most efficient and what asyncio syntax should we use?

### Update

Thanks to @user4815162342 who solved my problem. I've been playing around with his solution and I post runnable code below if someone else want to play around with asyncio.

```
import asyncio
import random
 
my_url_list = ['exemple.com/table1', 'exemple.com/table2', 'exemple.com/table3']


# Random sleeps to simulate requests to the server
async def randsleep(caller=None):
    i = random.randint(1, 6)
    if caller:
        print(f"Request HTML for {caller} sleeping for {i} seconds.")
    await asyncio.sleep(i)


async def process_urls(url_list):
    print(f'async def process_urls: added {url_list}')
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(5)
    coros = [process_user_list(table, limit) for table in url_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)


async def process_user_list(table, limit):
    async with limit:
        # Simulate HTML request and extracting urls to populate user_list
        await randsleep(table)
        if table[-1] == '1':
            user_list = ['exemple.com/user1', 'exemple.com/user2', 'exemple.com/user3']
        elif table[-1] == '2':
            user_list = ['exemple.com/user4', 'exemple.com/user5', 'exemple.com/user6']
        else:
            user_list = ['exemple.com/user7', 'exemple.com/user8', 'exemple.com/user9']

        print(f'async def process_user_list: Extracted {user_list} from {table}')

    # Execute process_user in parallel, but do so outside the `async with`
    # because process_user will also need the semaphore, and we don't need
    # it any more since we're done with fetching HTML.
    coros = [process_user(user, limit) for user in user_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)


async def process_user(user, limit):
    async with limit:
        # Simulate HTML request and extracting urls to populate user_subcat_list
        await randsleep(user)
        user_subcat_list = [user + '/profile', user + '/info', user + '/followers']
        print(f'async def process_user: Extracted {user_subcat_list} from {user}')

    coros = [process_subcat(subcat, limit) for subcat in user_subcat_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)


async def process_subcat(subcat, limit):
    async with limit:
        # Simulate HTML request and extracting content
        await randsleep(subcat)
        print(f'async def process_subcat: Extracted content from {subcat}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(process_urls(my_url_list))
```

Comment: The most important aspects are: `asyncio.gather()` to run everything in parallel, `asyncio.Semaphore` to prevent too many things running in parallel. See my answer for details and almost-runnable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's restructure the sync code so that each piece that can access the network is in a separate function. The functionality is unchanged, but it will make things easier later:

```
def process_urls(url_list):
    for table in url_list:
        process_user_list(table)

def process_user_list(table):
    # Get HTML, extract user_list
    for user in user_list:
        process_user(user)

def process_user(user):
    # Get HTML, extract user_subcat_list
    for subcat in user_subcat_list:
        process_subcat(subcat)

def process_subcat(subcat):
    # get HTML, extract content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_urls(my_url_list)
```

Assuming that the order of processing doesn't matter, we'd like the async version to run all the functions that are now called in `for` loops in parallel. They'll still run on a single thread, but they will `await` anything that might block, allowing the event loop to parallelize the waiting and drive them to completion by resuming each coroutine whenever it is ready to proceed. This is achieved by spawning each coroutine as a separate task that runs independent of other tasks and therefore in parallel. For example, a sequential (but still async) version of `process_urls` would look like this:

```
async def process_urls(url_list):
    for table in url_list:
        await process_user_list(table)
```

This is async because it is running inside an event loop, and you could run several such functions in parallel (which we'll show how to do shortly), but it's also sequential because it chooses to `await` each invocation of `process_user_list`. At each loop iteration the `await` explicitly instructs asyncio to suspend execution of `process_urls` until the result of `process_user_list` is available.

What we want instead is to tell asyncio to run all invocations of `process_user_list` in parallel, and to suspend execution of `process_urls` until they're all done. The basic primitive to spawn a coroutine in the "background" is to schedule it as a *task* using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), which is the closest async equivalent of a light-weight thread. Using `create_task` the parallel version of `process_urls` would look like this:

```
async def process_urls(url_list):
    # spawn a task for each table
    tasks = []
    for table in url_list:
        asyncio.create_task(process_user_list(table))
        tasks.append(task)
    # The tasks are now all spawned, so awaiting any one task lets
    # them all run.
    for task in tasks:
        await task
```

At first glance the second loop looks like it awaits tasks in sequence like the previous version, but this is not the case. Since each `await` suspends to the event loop, awaiting any task allows *all* tasks to progress, as long as they were scheduled beforehand using `create_task()`. The total waiting time will be no longer than the time of the longest task, [regardless of the order in which they finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898).

This pattern is used so often that asyncio has a dedicated utility function for it, [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). Using this function the same code can be expressed in a much shorter version:

```
async def process_urls(url_list):
    coros = [process_user_list(table) for table in url_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

But there is another thing to take care of: since `process_user_list` will get HTML from the server and there will be many instances of it running in parallel, and we cannot allow it to hammer the server with hundreds of simultaneous connections. We could create a pool of worker tasks and some sort of queue, but asyncio offers a more elegant solution: the [semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). Semaphore is a synchronization device that doesn't allow more than a pre-determined number of activations in parallel, making the rest wait in line.

The final version of `process_urls` creates a semaphore and just passes it down. It doesn't activate the semaphore because `process_urls` doesn't actually fetch any HTML itself, so there is no reason for it to hold a semaphore slot while `process_user_list`s are running.

```
async def process_urls(url_list):
    limit = asyncio.Semaphore(5)
    coros = [process_user_list(table, limit) for table in url_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

`process_user_list` looks similar, but it does need to activate the semaphore using `async with`:

```
async def process_user_list(table, limit):
    async with limit:
        # Get HTML using aiohttp, extract user_list

    # Execute process_user in parallel, but do so outside the `async with`
    # because process_user will also need the semaphore, and we don't need
    # it any more since we're done with fetching HTML.
    coros = [process_user(user, limit) for user in user_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

`process_user` and `process_subcat` are more of the same:

```
async def process_user(user, limit):
    async with limit:
        # Get HTML, extract user_subcat_list
    coros = [process_subcat(subcat, limit) for subcat in user_subcat_list]
    await asyncio.gather(*coros)

def process_subcat(subcat, limit):
    async with limit:
        # get HTML, extract content
    # do something with content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(process_urls(my_url_list))
```

In practice you will probably want the async functions to share the same aiohttp session, so you'd probably create it in the top-level function (`process_urls` in your case) and pass it down along with the semaphore. Each function that fetches HTML would have another `async with` for the aiohttp request/response, such as:

```
async with limit:
    async with session.get(url, params...) as resp:
        # get HTML data here
        resp.raise_for_status()
        resp = await resp.read()
# extract content from HTML data here
```

The two `async with`s can be collapsed into one, reducing the indentation but keeping the same meaning:

```
async with limit, session.get(url, params...) as resp:
    # get HTML data here
    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp = await resp.read()
# extract content from HTML data here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I will play around with some code tomorrow and reach back to you if any questions arise. I mark this as the correct answer, it definitely made my asyncio journey much more pleasant.

Comment: I got a new related question. Let’s assume that my_url_list is equal to ['exemple.com']. The 'exemple.com' page uses JavaScript (JS) to load 'table1'. To load 'table2', 'table3' we must push a button which make a JS call and load the next table in the same frame. If we ignore the syntax to load and navigate JS asynchronous. How should we implement the same asynchronous functionality as before? I suppose we need to yield each 'user_list' and await the request so the code doesn’t get stuck. Unfortunately, I haven't found exactly how I should do this.

Comment: @Sputnik The code in the answer loads all tables in parallel, for example each table would be loaded in `process_user_list` which receives a table name. I don't think any yielding is necessary, but I could be misunderstanding what you are asking. Please post this as a separate question, preferably with a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I came here from an advanced google search, wow, what a detailed explanation :)