# Can't figure out how to correctly schedule my asyncio functions

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm rather new to asyncio and I read through some documentation, examples, and other questions, but I can't find any answers as to what I'm doing wrong here. I don't quite understand enough about asyncio to diagnose why this is happening. I have a class with asyncio functions, one of which opens a websocket and then creates three asyncio tasks which it executes. The first executes completely fine. I'm confused with the execution of the second and third tasks. Even after the second one has executed asyncio.sleep, the third task seems to not execute websock.recv(), and so the second task executes websocket.recv() and gets sent the data that I meant for the third task to receive. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: Sorry the code isn't runnable unless you create or have a discord bot and use it's token in the code.

```
import websockets
import requests
import asyncio
import json

class GatewayConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heartbeat = None
        self.s = None
        self.info = None
        self.connected = False

        self.uri = f"{self.get_gateway()}/?v=8&encoding=json"

    @staticmethod
    def get_gateway():
        endpoint = requests.get(OAUTH+'gateway')
        return endpoint.json()['url']

    async def get_gateway_info(self, websock):
        recv = json.loads(await websock.recv())
        self.heartbeat = recv['d']['heartbeat_interval']
        self.s = recv['s']

    async def finish_gateway_connect(self, websock):
        await websock.send(json.dumps({
            'op': 2,
            'd': {
                'token': TOKEN,
                'intents': 513,
                'properties': {
                    '$os': 'windows',
                    '$browser': 'Sheepp',
                    '$device': 'Sheepp'
                }
            }
        }))

        print("waiting to received ready info")
        self.info = json.loads(await websock.recv())
        print("Ready info received")
        print(self.info)

    async def communicate(self):
        async with websockets.connect(self.uri) as websock:
            self.connected = True

            get = asyncio.create_task(self.get_gateway_info(websock))
            heartbeat = asyncio.create_task(self.send_heartbeat(websock))
            finish = asyncio.create_task(self.finish_gateway_connect(websock))

            await get  # First task
            await heartbeat  # Second task
            await finish  # Third task
        
    async def send_heartbeat(self, websock):
        while self.connected:
            await websock.send(json.dumps({'op': 1, 'd': self.s}))
            print("Sent heartbeat")
            response = json.loads(await websock.recv())
            print("Received 'heartbeat'")
            if response['op'] != 11:
                self.connected = False  # Discord api says to terminate connection upon not receiving a valid heartbeat response
                print(f"The server did not send back a valid heartbeat response, but instead: {response}")
            await asyncio.sleep(self.heartbeat/1000)

gateway = GatewayConnection()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(gateway.communicate())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Keyboard Interruption")
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Did you mean `get`, `heartbeat` and `finish` to get executed one after the other? Because, the way you coded their awaits, they will be executed _in parallel_, despite appearances.

Comment: Now that I think about it I should probably execute `get` first, not as a task. But I mean for the second and third task to be executed at the same time. My plan is that heartbeat is continually executed while other things are also executed because the heartbeat has to be maintained. I also need to execute `heartbeat` before `finish`

Comment: Then maybe you can use something like `await self.get_gateway_info(websock); await asyncio.gather(self.send_heartbeat(websock), self.finish_gateway_connect(websock))`

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error: `cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message`. The output from the print statements is in the following order: `Sent heartbeat`, `waiting to receive ready info`, `received 'heartbeat'`, `sleep`. I added th at last print statement right before the `asyncio.sleep` in `send_heartbeat`. Also the error occurs from the `recv` in `finish_gateway_connect`

Comment: @user4815162342 why do you think get, heartbeat and finish will run in parallel? They have an await therefore the next line won't run until first await has completed. await one(), await two() will run two once one has finished.

Comment: @InfoLearner They will run in parallel because they are first spawned as tasks (which allows them to run "in the background", i.e. during any `await`) and only then awaited. Awaiting the coroutines without first spawning them as tasks, as in `await self.get_gateway_info(websock); await self.send_heartbeat(websock); await self.finish_gateway_connect(websock)` would behave as you expect. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898) for a longer discussion of this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error I was getting, I made a separate class for handling the websocket which makes sure that the recv and send functions are executed in time correctly. I'm not sure about how well I made the class but here it is:

```
class WebsocketHandler:
    def __init__(self, websocket):
        self.ws = websocket
        self.sending = False

        self.sends = []
        self.recvs = []

    async def send(self, data):
        if self.sending:
            self.sends.append(json.dumps(data))
        else:
            self.sending = True
            await self.ws.send(json.dumps(data))
            while self.sends:
                data = self.sends[0]
                self.sends.pop(0)
                await self.ws.send(json.dumps(data))
            self.sending = False

    async def recv(self):
        event = asyncio.Event()
        self.recvs.append(event)
        while self.recvs[0] != event:
            await event.wait()
        try:
            data = await asyncio.wait_for(self.ws.recv(), timeout=1)
        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            self.recvs.pop(0)
            raise asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
        self.recvs.pop(0)
        if len(self.recvs) > 0:
            self.recvs[0].set()
        return json.loads(data)
```

The error I was getting was `RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message`
Edit: Feel free to critique my code.

Edit 2: I made a couple changes as needed to fix some errors I was getting as well as for convenience sake.

Comment: You could use an [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) in place of the loop with sleep.