# How to use asyncio.wait on an growing set of tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

In the following code, a task `A` is created and added to a set of tasks `tasks`.
I then use `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` to wait for the tasks to be finished.

But this does not take in consideration task `B1` which is created *inside* task `A` (recursive function call).

Then the following code doesn't wait for `B1` to finish: see the result below, the task `B1` never finishes.

I think the reason is that when `tasks` is evaluated on line (**), it still has **one single element**.

**Question: how to make `await asyncio.wait(tasks)` work on an evolving/growing set of tasks?**

```
import asyncio

tasks = set()
i = 0

async def mytask(s):
    global i
    print('mytask %s starting' % s)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if i < 4:    # limit number of tasks
        print('mytask %s creating new task' % s)
        i += 1
        tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(mytask('B%i' % i)))
    print('mytask %s len tasks:' % s, len(tasks))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('mystak %s finished' % s)

async def main():
    print('main starting')
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(mytask('A')))
    print('len tasks:', len(tasks))
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)            # (**)
    # await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('main finished')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
main starting
len tasks: 1
mytask A starting
mytask A creating new task
mytask A len tasks: 2
mytask B1 starting       # <--- mytask B1 will never complete!
mystak A finished
main finished
```

If we replace line (**) by `await asyncio.sleep(10)`, of course, all tasks will complete:

```
main starting
len tasks: 1
mytask A starting
mytask A creating new task
mytask A len tasks: 2
mytask B1 starting
mystak A finished
mytask B1 creating new task
mytask B1 len tasks: 3
mytask B2 starting
mystak B1 finished
mytask B2 creating new task
mytask B2 len tasks: 4
mytask B3 starting
mystak B2 finished
mytask B3 creating new task
mytask B3 len tasks: 5
mytask B4 starting
mystak B3 finished
mytask B4 len tasks: 5
mystak B4 finished
main finished
```

Comment: Couldn't task A simply await the function B? That way you could wait just for the top-level taska rather than the whole tree.

Comment: Tasks create new tasks recursively, I edited to give a better example, @user4815162342.

Comment: Sure, but each task could await the tasks it creates directly (along with its own work). That way each task is "responsible" for the stuff it has spawned directly, and you don't need to maintain a global set. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start off with answering your question directly, you can wait for a dynamic set of tasks with a loop, such as:

```
while tasks:
    prev_tasks = tasks.copy()
    # use gather() so exceptions are propagated rather than discarded
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    tasks.difference_update(prev_tasks)
```

But you probably don't need to do that. Instead, you can have each task wait for the subtask(s) it's created, along with its own work. That way you don't need to even have a global set of tasks, nor do you need to worry about waiting all of them in `main()`:

```
import asyncio

i = 0

async def mytask(s):
    global i
    print('mytask %s starting' % s)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    if i < 4:    # limit number of tasks
        print('mytask %s creating new task' % s)
        i += 1
        task = asyncio.create_task(mytask('B%i' % i))
    else:
        task = None
    print('mytask %s len tasks:' % s, i)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)   # our actual work
    print('mystak %s finished' % s)
    # after doing the work, wait for the child task if we created one
    if task is not None:
        await task

async def main():
    print('main starting')
    await mytask('A')
    # await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print('main finished')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thakns for this great answer @user4815162342! Sidenote: I notice that it's faster (a few seconds) with your `task = asyncio.create_task(mytask('B%i' % i))` instead of `task = mytask('B%i' % i)` but why? In both cases it's an async job, and we await for it at the end of `mytask`. What's the real difference here?

Comment: @Basj `create_task()` is actually needed here because it spawns the task in the background and allows it to run while we're awaiting "actual work". On the other hand, if you just _call_ `mytask()`, it is not yet submitted to the event loop, so it won't magically run while we're doing the other await. (This is one dfifference between how Python and JavaScript do async.) In other words, by removing that call to `create_task()`, you inadvertently removed parallelism as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898) for a more detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

A `asyncio.wait` is called with a list of one element, until its start/processing there is no B task. In your case the simplest solution is just to await the B task in the A, but A won't return until B is done.

If that doesn't suite you could use some kind of busy waiting - a infinite loop that checks tasks length:

```
import asyncio

tasks = set()


async def mytask(s):
    print('mytask %s starting' % s)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('mytask %s create new task' % s)
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(mytask('B')))
    print('mytask %s len tasks:' % s, len(tasks))
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('mystak %s finished' % s)

async def main():
    print('main starting')
    tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(mytask('A')))
    print('len tasks:', len(tasks))
    while True:
        if all([task.done() for task in tasks]): break
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print('main finished')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Keep in mind that busy waiting is often overused. Moreover it looks like implementing a task scheduler on top of the asyncio's task scheduler (which under the hood has `while True` as well).

Another solution is to [`run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) the loop instead of `asyncio.run`. It feels good for a worker long running applications.

```
asyncio.ensure_future(main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

You could also refactor the code to utilize [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) and await with `Queue.join` to all items processed.

Comment: I've added edited, only "all done" will break loop