# Why you cannot await a python coroutine object directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

So I am running an asyncio example:

```py
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await task1
    await task2

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This piece of code works correctly with output:

```
started at 14:36:06
hello
world
finished at 14:36:08
```

The 2 coroutines is running asynchronously, finally took 2 seconds, which has no problem.
However, when I combine the lines together and directly await the Task object, like this:

```py
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
    # around 2 seconds.)
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This result becomes:

```
started at 14:37:12
hello
world
finished at 14:37:15
```

which took 3 seconds, indicating that coroutine running incorrectly.

How can I make the latter code working properly? or is there something idk resulting in this difference?

P.S. The example acturally comes from python doc: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines

Comment: The strange thing about `await asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))` is that you create a task object but then immediately wait on it. Its the same thing as `await say_after(1, 'hello')`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898) also covers this question in some detail.

Answer (score 2):

`await` makes it so that code 'stops' and continues after the awaited coroutine is completed, so when you write

```
await asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
```

the second task is created and run *after* the first coroutine was completed, therefore it takes 3 seconds total. As a solution, consider using a function like `gather` or `wait`. For example:

```py
    import asyncio, time
    
    async def say_after(delay, what):
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(what)
    
    async def main():
        print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

        # Wait until both tasks are completed (should take
        # around 2 seconds.)
        await asyncio.gather(say_after(1, 'hello'), say_after(2, 'world'))

        print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
started at 08:10:04
hello
world
finished at 08:10:06
```

Comment: Yeah I know I could use asyncio.gather / asyncio.wait, and the coroutines would work perfectly...

Comment: However, as you've explained `the second task is created and run after the first coroutine was completed`, why the former code can work properly?

Comment: It's just how the await statement is designed, your first example is also fine. Just make sure you create the tasks before you await them, because `create_task` allows them to get scheduled.

Comment: @SimZhou Your first example works because both tasks are already scheduled through `create_task` when the first await is called.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs [Await expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await-expression):

> Suspend the execution of coroutine on an awaitable object. Can only be
> used inside a coroutine function.

Whenever you `await`, the routine is suspended until the waited task completes. In the first example, both coroutines start and the 2 second sleep in the second overlaps the first. By the time you start running after the first `await`, 1 second has already elapsed in the second timer.

In the second example, the second `await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))` isn't scheduled until after the first completes and `main` continues running. That's when the 2 second sleep for the second task begins.

I've combined the examples to show the progression. Instead of the original prints, I print a start message before `say_after` awaits and a finish message just after main's `await`. You can see the time difference in the results.

```
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f"start {what} at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
    await task1
    print(f"Finished hello at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await task2
    print(f"Finished world at {time.strftime('%X')}")

async def main2():
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    print(f"Finished hello at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))
    print(f"Finished world at {time.strftime('%X')}")

print("========== Test 1 ============")
asyncio.run(main())

print("========== Test 2 ============")
asyncio.run(main2())
```

The results of the second test show that the second `say_after` isn't called until the first completes.

```
========== Test 1 ============
start hello at 00:51:42
start world at 00:51:42
hello
Finished hello at 00:51:43
world
Finished world at 00:51:44
========== Test 2 ============
start hello at 00:51:44
hello
Finished hello at 00:51:45
start world at 00:51:45
world
Finished world at 00:51:47
```

In `main`, tasks are created to run `asyncio.sleep`, but those tasks aren't actually run until `main` returns to the even loop. If we add a `time.sleep(3)` we might expect these two overlapped async sleeps to already be complete, but in fact `say_after` isn't even run until the first `await` that lets the event loop continue.

```
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f"starting {what} at {time.time()-start}")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    global start
    print('time asyncio.sleep with intermedite time.sleep')
    start = time.time()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

    # similate working for 3 seconds with non asyncio sleep
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')
    await task1  # <== where the 2 `say_after` tasks start
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')
    await task2
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Produces

```
time asyncio.sleep with intermedite time.sleep
expect 3 got 3.0034446716308594
starting hello at 3.003699541091919
starting world at 3.0038907527923584
hello
expect 3 got 4.005880355834961
world
expect 3 got 5.00671124458313
```

Adding an `asyncio.sleep(0)` to `main` after setting up the tasks allows them to run and do their own overlapped sleeps and the code works as we want.

```
import asyncio, time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    print(f"starting {what} at {time.time()-start}")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    global start
    print('time asyncio.sleep with event loop poll and intermedite time.sleep')
    start = time.time()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'hello'))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))

    # let the `say_after` tasks (and anything else pending) run
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

    # similate working for 3 seconds with non asyncio sleep
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')
    await task1  # <== where the 2 `say_after` tasks start
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')
    await task2
    print(f'expect 3 got {time.time()-start}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you effort but I don't think you are right on `By the time you start running after the first await, 1 second has already elapsed`! To prove this, try add a line of `time.sleep(3)` after `task2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'world'))`. So if you were right, the two coroutines should finish at the same time. However it is not!

Comment: @YihuaZhou `time.sleep()` confounds the issue because it stops the whole event loop and therefore all coroutines. You should **never** call `time.sleep()` when using or testing asyncio; `await asyncio.sleep()` instead.

Comment: @user4815162342 - I get your point, but I tried the `sleep(3)` and it did add a 3 second delay, which I find very puzzling. All `asyncio.sleep` does is schedule a very boring completion routine in the future. `time.sleep(3)` is a standin for anything that eats CPU - say, a `pandas` transformation. I can't figure out why the `asyncio.sleep` delays until the scheduling coroutine does something to go back to the event loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood where you added `sleep(3)` which added the 3-second delay, could you be more specific? Also, does `sleep(3)` mean that you used `await asyncio.sleep(3)` or that you used `time.sleep(3)`? As for pandas and such, if you need to call CPU-bound code from asyncio, you should use [`run_in_executor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) to avoid the event loop being hatled.

Comment: @user4815162342 I added `time.sleep(3)` just before `await task1` on the first example. `asyncio.sleep` creates a future and does `call_later` with the time delta. I assumed that timeout should start counting down right then, but it seems to wait until `await task1`. Seems I have some studying to do.

Comment: @user4815162342 - The `say_after` tasks which schedule the `asyncio.sleep` isn't running until the first `await` is called, and that's why the time doesn't start til then. I think I was working too late last night.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda understand the question now...

await makes the process blocked at that line.

So in the main function, if you want to do parrellel tasks, better use asyncio.wait/gather...

I think it is just the design style of Asyncio which makes the former code working well...