# Python: How to obtain return value from only one function (out of several executed with asyncio.gather)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What is a good way to run functions with `asyncio.gather` and get the return value from only one of the executed functions? This might be more of a novice Python syntax question than it has to do with `asyncio` per se but my example script below uses it.

```
async def interval():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def check_messages():
    received_messages = await check_for_new_messages()
    return received_messages

asyncio def main():
    _interval, received_messages = await asyncio.gather(interval(), check_messages())
    if received_messages:
        # process them
```

I basically want `received_messages` back from `check_messages()`, but `interval()` doesn't even return a value so it is unneeded. Is there a nicer way of doing this than having to create `_interval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, you don't need to change anything. You can shorten `_interval` to `_` if it's too long as it is. You can avoid the other variable completely with `received_messages = (await asyncio.gather(interval(), check_messages()))[1]`, but that's just less readable.

Another option is not to use `gather` at all, but spawn two tasks and await them. It doesn't lead to less code, but here it is for completeness:

```
asyncio def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(interval())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(messaages())
    await t1
    received_messages = await t2
    if received_messages:
        # process them
```

Note that the above code *will* run `interval()` and `messages()` in parallel, despite the use of `await`, because both are spawned as tasks prior to the first `await` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60674375/1600898) for a more detailed explanation.