# Simplest way to gracefully cancel an asyncio job in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I've been playing around with an API, and call a function when a specific string is caught.

At the moment, I'm using sys.exit inside the function to end the script. However that causes an error:

```
_ClientEventTask exception was never retrieved
future: <ClientEventTask state=finished event=on_message coro=<bound method MyClient.on_message of <__main__.MyClient object at 0x123b20a00>> exception=SystemExit()>
```

I'd like to shutdown the script gracefully. The relevant code snippet is here:

```
class MyClient(API.Client):

      async def on_message(self, message):

        if (message.channel.id == XXX): 
            dostuff(message.content)

client = MyClient()

client.run('XXX')
```

I've tried a number of things and am a little stuck. Would greatly appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `Task.cancel()`? This post may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016501/how-to-schedule-and-cancel-tasks-with-asyncio, as well as this article: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/python/asyncio-graceful-shutdown/.

Comment: Thanks for those - I have looked at them and unfortunately can’t see an easy way to modify my code to achieve the same in my code example.

I’m really only two weeks into coding with python (haven’t really done any coding since qbasic back in high school!), hence there’s a bit of a steep learning curve for me. Though this is the first time I’ve been stuck on something for more than half a day haha.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to achieve what you want is to replace `sys.exit()` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()`.

Comment: Thanks for this! What worked well was just adding asyncio.get_event_loop().stop() to the end of the function that was called. Changing client.run to client.start threw an error, so I kept it as client.run.

Comment: @user15273025 I've now amended the answer.