# asyncio end script when done

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Can someone give me a tip on how to (understand asnycio) use asnycio to do this:

1. `on_start`  - method run only once when script starts
2. `get_sensor_readings` - method run while event is True
3. `evauluate_data` - method run while event is True
4. `check_time` - method run while event is True to see if the event is
   still True
5. `on_end` - method run only once when event has expired before script ends

This script below works, just simulating how long the method will execute I used `random` package `await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))` just to add some randomness for the bullet points above 2,3,4.

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td
import random
import time

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duration_in_seconds = 60
        self.program_start = dt.now()
        self.event_has_expired = False


    async def on_start(self):
        print("On Start Event Start! Applying Overrides!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))


    async def on_end(self):
        print("On End Releasing All Overrides!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))
        

    async def get_sensor_readings(self):
        print("getting sensor readings!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))   

 
    async def evauluate_data(self):
        print("checking data!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))   


    async def check_time(self):
        if (dt.now() - self.program_start > td(seconds = self.duration_in_seconds)):
            self.event_has_expired = False
            print("Event is DONE!!!")

        else:
            print("Event is not done! ",dt.now() - self.program_start)



    async def main(self):

        # script starts, do only once self.on_start()
        await self.on_start()
        print("On Start Done!")
        
        while not self.event_has_expired:

            await self.get_sensor_readings()
            await self.evauluate_data()
            await self.check_time()

        # script ends, do only once self.on_end() when even is done
        await self.on_end()
        print('Done Deal!')


async def main():
    program = Program()
    await program.main()

asyncio.run(main())
```

What I notice is the scripts still keeps running

```
On Start Event Start! Applying Overrides!!!
going into event intermission mode
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is not done!  0:00:23.131918
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is not done!  0:00:31.211425
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is not done!  0:00:43.272416
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is not done!  0:00:52.362870
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is DONE!!!
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is DONE!!!
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
Event is DONE!!!
getting sensor readings!!!
checking data!!!
```

Any tips greatly appreciated. How do I `cancel` coroutines when the `Event is DONE` and then move into running the `on_end` method only once before the script ends?

Comment: I guess the method `check_time` should set the attribute `event_has_expired = True`

Comment: Would you have any tips on how to implement that?

Comment: Would I want to implement `task.cancel()` like this in the SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016501/how-to-schedule-and-cancel-tasks-with-asyncio

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta as td
import random
import time

class Program:
    def __init__(self):
        self.duration_in_seconds = 20
        self.program_start = dt.now()
        self.event_has_expired = False
        self.canceled_success = False

        

    async def on_start(self):
        print("On Start Event Start! Applying Overrides!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))


    async def on_end(self):
        print("On End Releasing All Overrides!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))
        

    async def get_sensor_readings(self):
        print("getting sensor readings!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))   

 
    async def evauluate_data(self):
        print("checking data!!!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(3, 9))   


    async def check_time(self):
        if (dt.now() - self.program_start > td(seconds = self.duration_in_seconds)):
            self.event_has_expired = True
            print("Event is DONE!!!")

        else:
            print("Event is not done! ",dt.now() - self.program_start)



    async def main(self):
        # script starts, do only once self.on_start()
        await self.on_start()
        print("On Start Done!")

        while not self.canceled_success:

            readings = asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_sensor_readings())
            analysis = asyncio.ensure_future(self.evauluate_data())
            checker = asyncio.ensure_future(self.check_time())
            
            if not self.event_has_expired:
                await readings   
                await analysis           
                await checker
                
            else:
                # close other tasks before final shutdown
                readings.cancel()
                analysis.cancel()
                checker.cancel()
                self.canceled_success = True
                print("cancelled hit!")


        # script ends, do only once self.on_end() when even is done
        await self.on_end()
        print('Done Deal!')


async def main():
    program = Program()
    await program.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugging nit: prior to `await self.on_end()` you should `print` something.
Doesn't matter for this question, as apparently we never get that far.

---

You believe that check_time changed `self.event_has_expired`,
yet the `while` loop doesn't see it change.

I am reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html).

It suggests using a synchronization primitive such as
a [condition variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) from the threading
or perhaps from the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Condition) libraries.

But now as I read the comments,
I see that @svex99 correctly diagnosed the trouble -- you initialize
the variable to `False` and then upon "change" you again make it `False`.
So of course the `while` loop will never terminate.

Let us know how testing goes once you adjust that detail.

Comment: I put an answer in that appears to work but a little unsure about how asnycio works...